# Передать Token из Cookies серверу (angular to laravel)

Tags: angularjs, laravel, http, cookie, angular2

После запроса Авторизации, сервер редиректит в "/" приложения и передает в Cookie XSRF-TOKEN и laravel-session.

Задача: передать при каждом последующем запросе этот **Token** в **'Params'**, получив его из Cookie

Как сделать?

Есть цикл, к примеру:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$cookies', function($http, $scope, $state, $cookies) {

  $http({
    method:'POST', 
    url:'https://mysite/api/acc_details', 
    params: {
        'token': $cookies.csrftoken

    }
})
```

Пробовал и `**config: $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.get('csrftoken')**,

Но в таком случае серверу придет заголовок, который он должен считывать. 
и $cookies.ge() постоянно в консоли выдает ошибку, что 'get' не определен.

Comment: каким образом сюда относится angular2?

Comment: Запрос идет с приложения на Angular к API  на сервер (laravel). @Grundy

Comment: angular и angular2 - абсолютно разные вещи, между особо не связанные

Comment: _Есть цикл, к примеру:_ - в приведенном коде **нет** цикла

Comment: Я задал просто вопрос: как достать Токен из cookie?  angular2 использует те же самые механизмы в данном случае, лишь немного видоизмененные.

Comment: доступ к кукам в первом и втором отличается разительно в зависимости от используемого модуля. _$cookies.ge() постоянно в консоли выдает ошибку, что 'get' не определен._ - метода `ge` действительно нет. Так же стоит добавить _текст ошибки_.

Answer (score 2):

Для ANgular 2.0+: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html
Добавляем в бутстрап модуля:

```
{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('myCookieName', 'My-Header-Name')}
```

Comment: Можете подробнее объяснить на примере как использовать предложенное вами решение?